# How would I redirect a question towards the asker

Tags: conversations

I was wondering how I would be able to redirect a question regarding me towards the asker. For example, if I was asked "夏休みに何をしましたか。”, and responded with, "中国に行きました。本当に楽しかったよ。”, how would I then ask the other person how their summer was? I wanted to find out if there was anything easier to say rather than repeating the entire question back to them.

Answer (score 2):

In that context, I would say "あなたはどうでしたか?", which means "*How was your summer vacation?*".

"あなたはなにかしましたか?" also works, both means almost same but latter means "*What did you do in your summer vacation?*", so it's more closer to original question.

Answer (score 1):

One simple way that you can ask the same of your conversation partner is  by asking "Xは？" where X is an appropriate form of address for them.